# Header on top of side scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll, header, fullpage.js, mixitup

In the pages below I want the header and the menu just beneath it to have its full 100% width, meaning I want the side scrolling to show below the navbar.

In this page: http://raddar.pro/projects_7.html the side scrolling pushed the header and the menu beneath it to the left by its width, therefore it is not what I want. Are you able to help me amend the code please so that the header and the menu remain 100% screen width?

In this page: http://raddar.pro/projects_13.html I have tried "overflow: hidden" for the body and "overflow-y: scroll;" for the content below the header and the menu beneath the header, but it did not work.

In the page below I have managed to introduce a side scrolling which shows below the header and the menu beneath the header: 
http://raddar.pro/projects_12.html

On this page above I have put my content within the fullpage.js property of scrolling inside sections and slides (https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html#firstPage), however then I am not able to operate the content. Namely, the menu beneath the header does not work anymore, i.e. it does not filder the images of the MixItUp content that's placed within the fullpage.js section. In fact, sometimes it works but it is super random and I feel there is some overlap in the code which I am not able to discover (I have a feeling it is a javascript issue). It would be great if you could help me solve this because I actually really like the graphics of the scrolling within a fullpage.js section, which is alike the mobile phone scrolling and not as wide as the standard desktop browser side scrolling.

Below is some progress I made, but still not quite there

Option I:
http://raddar.pro/projects_14.html - here I am able to have the scrolling within fullpage.js, however the mixitup plugin doesn't work (ie the menu of mixitup plugin won't filter the images). Below is the code I put together:

```
     afterRender:  $(function () {
     var filterList = {init: function () {
     // MixItUp plugin
     // http://mixitup.io
     $('#portfoliolist').mixItUp({
     selectors: {
     target: '.portfolio',
     filter: '.filter'
     },
     load: {
     filter: '.architecture, .interiordesign, .urbandesign, .development, 
     .art, .branding, .raddar' // show app tab on first load
     }    
     });
     }
     };
     // Run the show!
     filterList.init();
     }),
```

Option II:
http://raddar.pro/projects_15.html - here mixitup plugin works however there is no scrolling, so i am not able to see all the images. i changed the "$" and "(" at start of the code and ")" at the end of the code:

```
     afterRender:  function () {
     var filterList = {init: function () {
     // MixItUp plugin
     // http://mixitup.io
     $('#portfoliolist').mixItUp({
     selectors: {
     target: '.portfolio',
     filter: '.filter'
     },
     load: {
     filter: '.architecture, .interiordesign, .urbandesign, .development, 
     .art, .branding, .raddar' // show app tab on first load
     }    
     });
     }
     };
     // Run the show!
     filterList.init();
     },
```

Comment: Please provide example code and/or code sandbox links rather than just link us to your project. SO can help you with specific questions, not debug your code.

Comment: hi hi, many thanks for your feedback! I have made some changes to the above description, namely putting the MixItUp plugin code withing the fullpage.js code (by using fullpage.js's "after Render" callback. However I am still not able to run it properly. Below please see the main part of the code which I think you can give me feedback on:

Answer (score 0):

I have gave a quick check on **MixItUp**, however I don't have time to familiarize it. I seems this is a very go tool.

But I think your problem is much simpler when just using basic HTML coding:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #363636;
}

#menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 93px);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 10px;
}

.showItem {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test Scroll </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="container">
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                <div class="showItem"></div>
                
            </div>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I guess this is what your looking for?

Comment: thank you, however the code's you've shared does not allow to filter the images from the grey menu (right beneath the header). if you go on the link http://raddar.pro/projects_7.html you will see that once you click on say "branding" of the grey submenu the images will shuffle and then if you click on architecture you will get a different shuffle that represents projects related to architecture.

Comment: Of course the code above won't provide further functions that you are trying to a complish like "filtering selection item by click the menu". My code is just a page structure that solves the problem you asked in your question, "you want the scroll bar only show under the header and menu bar". Any extra functions you need is what you should be adding in based on the structure, that is if you are looking for the scroll bar on the page located like the one I made here.

Comment: thank you for your help, but i suppose i need help on the particular plug in as well, because scrolling as you've describe it wouldn't work with the plug in unfortunately